# OnClickListener() must override a superclass method?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button

With this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
. . .

Button buttonAuthorizeUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAuthorizeUsers);
    buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this, Configure_Activity.class);  
            OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure); 
        }
      });
```

I'm getting:

*The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method*

It would seem that this problem is sometimes caused by a Project | Properties | Java Compiler being set to 1.5.

Although I'm virtually I'd had this problem before, and changed it to 1.6, somehow it WAS 1.5 again.

HOWEVER, that (changing it to 1.6) did not solve the problem. I'm still getting that same err msg, after cleaning, building, and F11ing...???

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would recommend that you uncheck "Enable project specific settings", click "Configure Workspace Settings..." and change "Compiler Compliance Level" to 1.6 or above. Otherwise you would have to specify it every time.

If you need a specific compliance level for a specific project, you need to verify every other project that need compliance level 1.6 or above is set to this.

After everything is correctly setup - clean projects and **restart Eclipse**. Eclipse can be such a bitch some times - this often solves problems for me.

Comment: restart Eclipse -> very important step! +1 because that's what solved my problem

Comment: Even after I applied all the steps above and restarted Eclipse, the error was still there. I had to replace "new OnClickListener ..." by " new View.OnClickListener ..." to get a clean compile. Then, I did return to "new OnClickListener ..." and things remained ok. Clearly an eclipse (Juno) problem !

Comment: I tried everything but finally restart Eclipse did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Two things to consider:

<s>1) Take a look at your imports - are you sure that `View.OnClickListener` is imported, but not lets say `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`</s>

2) `OnClickListener` is actually an interface, that you are instantiating anonymously. So after all when writing the `onClick` method you are actually not overriding a super class method, but instead implementing an interface method. Annotating interface methods with `@Override` is a good practice, but this has been introduced in JDK 6, which means that by the time Android 1.5 or 1.6 was developed this may not has been yet introduced to the java language and hence making it an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Right below the "Compiler Compliance Level", there are a few options grayed out if the "Use default compliance settings" checkbox is checked:  Namely, "Generated .class files compatibility" and "Source compatibility".  Verify that both of those are set to 1.6 - If not, either change the default compliance settings, or uncheck that box and tweak them directly.

Comment: That all seems to be good, but the two "Disallow Identifiers" entries read "Error" Is this ok? Also, what I ramp it up from 1.6 to 1.7? Is that a possible fix?

Comment: I don't know what happens when you bump to 1.7-  As of this writing I'd put it up there with "Don't cross the streams".  As for "Disallow Identifiers"-  That usually means you've got a variable name somewhere that's a reserved keyword, like "assert" or "enum".  You'll have to check the line number.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Button buttonAuthorizeUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAuthorizeUsers);
   buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent configure = new  Intent(OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this,Configure_Activity.class);  
           OnDemandAndAutomatic_Activity.this.startActivity(configure); 
      }
   });
```

try to replace this line

```
buttonAuthorizeUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {});
```

this error you got happened when your trying to assignee the On-click to unexpected type !
So, beleive me Eclipse IDE most of time will import *DialogInterface* instead of *View* so write it by your self.

Comment: That doesn't seem to tbe problem. I added my imports above.

Comment: Ok, can you work around this issue ! like let the activity implements the `View.OnClickListener` interface and override the method onclick then set the onClick this -> `.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 2):

daigoor is right. Eclipse always try to do this '**import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener**' instead of the doing this -> '**import android.view.View.OnClickListener**'. That solves my problem.