# compiler compliance level vs. superclass overwrite

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to compile my project, but it didn't, cause of this error:

```
The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method
```

so i googled it up and found this: [OnClickListener() must override a superclass method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026918/onclicklistener-must-override-a-superclass-method)

it fixed my problem, but now i have an "invisible" error, which just tells me there is a single error in my whole file, but i can't see where. If i try to compile it tells me this:

```
[2013-02-18 23:25:43 - Datenbank] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

And well, if i do that, I'm back at the start, and have problems with the override superclass method!

What to do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler `1.7` corresponds to `Java 7`. As of now, Android does not support `Java 7`. You must either use `Java 5` or `Java 6`, but `Java 5` results in errors with the `@Override` annotation.

To fix this, make sure you have JDK 6 installed. Then right click on your project from the navigator, go to `Properties -> Java Compiler`. Then check `Enable Project Specific settings` and select `1.6` from the first drop down.

Comment: Thank you! just found this out the same moment too and came here to answer my own question :D
Didn't find the reason why it didn't work, so big thx for you explaining it!
got 10 minutes cooldown on accepting the answer, I'll check back to accept it soon (:

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to with the Android project in whole rather than the source file. Take a look at
[Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637144/android-requires-compiler-compliance-level-5-0-or-6-0-found-1-7-instead-plea)