# @override error: The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I wanted to navigate to a new page when clicking a button. Below are my both activities I have created. I am using eclipse and I am getting an error saying `The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method` on the main activity.

This is my main activity.

```
package com.example.grammer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button grammerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.grammar);

   grammerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Grammer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });
} 
}
```

This is my second activity.

```
package com.example.grammer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;

public class Grammer extends Activity {

    @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grammer);

         Button grammerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grammar);


         grammerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          //    @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
              }

            });
          }
    }
```

Removing the `@override` will remove the error, but then app is not working as intended.

Comment: add this `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`. And add the @Override annotaion. Why do you need to call `finish()`?. Hardware back button does the job.

Comment: //    @Override -> remove // in the second class

Comment: @faz see the full answer , only need to change layout name and button id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

[OnClickListener() must override a superclass method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026918/onclicklistener-must-override-a-superclass-method)

Uncheck "Enable project specific settings", click "Configure Workspace Settings..." and change "Compiler Compliance Level" to 1.6 or above

Have this import statement

```
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

There is no need to remove @Override Annotation.

Also calling `finish()` is not necessary. The hardware back button does the job.

When you press back button in Grammar Activity your current activity is popped from the back stack and the previous activity in the back stack takes focus. So there is no need to call `finish()` on button click.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Also if you have a Button with id `grammar` in `activity_grammer.xml` it is ok.

Make sure you have a button with id `grammar` in `activity_grammer.xml`

You can read the topic id

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching.

Answer (score 1):

Change "Compiler Compliance Level" to 1.6. of java from project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code::

**Just replace then name of layout and button id by your**

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alayout);


    Button grammerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aId);

   grammerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Grammer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });

} 
}
```

**Just replace then name of layout and button id by your**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Grammer extends Activity {

    @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blayout);

         Button grammerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aId);


         grammerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
              }

            });
          }

    }
```

Comment: no not correct. id must be unique under the current view tree. Quoting docs "An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching". http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: @Raghunandan yes dude, I have done in previous a little mistake. So I have been edited the full answer. It is the solved code. Thanks for your that correction.

Comment: why should layout named by changed. wrong. they are 2 different layouts again

Comment: @Raghunandan what? can you explain in brief......... because what I have written here I have tested this and then write here. Please see his post in brief , he is also given two different layout name but same id for button. I have also done the same thing for his facility.

Comment: if its different layout with the same ids there is no problem. and op already has different layouts

Comment: If you have two different layouts and within those layout if you have same id then no problem. Its find the id from `setContentView(R.layout.layoutid);` only matter is which layout you have set.

Comment: I also say the same thing and same work...... so now what you are asking is there any difference? See my answer and then comments before that not given any bad idea. Because your comments and my work is same.

Comment: Why You have written this **Just replace then name of layout and button id by your** what is meaning of this line ??? Isn't you contradict your latest statement?? And by the way OP has different layout so having same id has no problem.

Comment: @user3110424 what are you saying I have also done the same thing. I have taken two different layouts but in both cases I have given same ID of button , and it's work fine. What you are saying I have done this. So why you are given wrong comments and also given -1 vote . I have been run this code. It really bad manner . I am very much upset .

Comment: @user3110424 please see his layout name "activity_main" "activity_grammer" and button id "grammar" for both layout, but in my code layout name "alayout" and "blayout" and button id "aId" . For this reason I have been told him to replace the layout name and button id by your . Is it anything wrong?

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee Dont be upset my friend.

Comment: @user3110424 no you are given wrong judgement the people , 1st time I was wrong, so i have edited, but you people saying some wrong thing. Don't do that, please see first then do this. If you are given -1 vote, it's nothing for me, but you are given wrong message in StackOverflow site. Be aware .

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee dont take this so seriously i was told what i have seen first. And if you are talking abt -1 i have given it when it was wrong. Edit your answer will give you upvote but dont take it so personal.

Comment: @user3110424 no dude after edit the vote is given, because I have watched this. I am not taking this personal , but I am upset about your -1 prove here that my answer is wrong but actually it's right. Nothing else.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee its not about right or wrong. Its about solving op's problem. You are suggesting op to use a different layout when op already has a different layout. Instead of commenting if you have a problem take it up @ meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Raghunandan why are commenting too much before see the answer. You are a talented person, but don't loose this in such a way. Please read my answer and as well as my comments to another person --- "@user3110424 please see his layout name "activity_main" "activity_grammer" and button id "grammar" for both layout, but in my code layout name "alayout" and "blayout" and button id "aId" . For this reason I have been told him to replace the layout name and button id by your . Is it anything wrong?"

Comment: No need of +1 dear, your +1 or -1 not need for me. It's about right and wrong. nothing else. Please leave this topics. I know I am right and also know that your 1st comment was right but after that you people are totally wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63895/who-has-downvoted-me-and-why and this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have no interest about this, if I do anything wrong then you tell me I will try to solve the wrong thing-- I think you have been already see this, but if I do right after that they tell me wrong or take any revenge I don't care those people. If your is big then you can think also big-- I believe this opinion. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to import the library for OnClickListener. Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in your eclipse and it will import the `import android.view.View.OnClickListener` file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

First, You havn't import `OnClickListener`

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

and second one

```
Button grammerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grammar);
```

you are giving same name for both **Button** Ids in different layouts. Make sure you have a **button** with id **grammar** in `activity_grammer.xml` present are not.

Comment: no need for different button ids if `activity_grammer.xml` has a button with id `grammar`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. edit your second part of the answer

Comment: @Raghunandan you are correct friend. i checked it it's working if there is no button in another xml it'll give NPE. and also i edited my ans.

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to import the `ViewClickListener` namespace in your code.

Just Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and it will add the relevant and missing namespaces in your project.